# Can a protobuf message be defined with 2 possible types?

Tags: protocol-buffers

For example I have a message that could be a string OR an array of strings. Is there a way to define that in the protobuf file? Or do I have to pick one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#using-oneof), but `oneof` cannot be mixed with `repeated`. But ultimately, `repeated` can store a `string` *or* multiple `string` values, so maybe just:

```proto
repeated string foo = 42;
```

Comment: So if I use the above solution with repeated-- if the user wants to pass a single string does it have to be within an array like this ["string"] or can it just be a "string"? I'm looking at the docs but it's not clear.

Comment: You can define another message that has a repeated string, if it matters to you so much that you don't want a single-string array. That way one option can be a string, the other can be a message with a repeated string field.